# redis-server in ubuntu14.04: Bind address already in use

Tags: redis, server, port, in-memory-database

I started redis server on ubuntu by typing this on terminal: $redis-server

This results in following > http://paste.ubuntu.com/12688632/

```
aruns ~ $ redis-server
27851:C 05 Oct 15:16:17.955 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
27851:M 05 Oct 15:16:17.957 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
27851:M 05 Oct 15:16:17.957 # Server can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
27851:M 05 Oct 15:16:17.958 # Current maximum open files is 4096. maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
27851:M 05 Oct 15:16:17.958 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use
```

How can I fix this problem, it there any manual or automated process to fix this binding.

Answer (score 144):

```
$ ps aux | grep redis
```

Find the port that its running on.. In my case..

```
MyUser  8821   0.0  0.0  2459704    596   ??  S    4:54PM   0:03.40 redis-server *:6379
```

And then close the port manually

```
$ kill -9 8821
```

Re-run redis

```
$ redis-server
```

Comment: `killall redis-server` would be simpler.

Comment: sudo service redis-server stop worked for me

Answer (score 142):

```
sudo service redis-server stop
```

Comment: This one worked like a charm for me. I am just wondering why? What does it do differently than 'killall redis-server'?

Comment: I tired them all and this is the only one that worked for me on Ubuntu

Comment: This should have been the top comment

Answer (score 33):

I solved this problem on Mac by just  typing `redis-cli shutdown`, after this just
re open the terminal and type `redis-server` and it will work .

Answer (score 17):

for me, after lots of problems, this solved my issue:

```
 root@2c2379a99b47:/home/ ps -aux | grep redis
    redis     3044  0.0  0.0  37000  8780 ?        Ssl  14:59   0:00 /usr/bin/redis-server *:6379
```

after finding redis, kill it!

```
root@2c2379a99b47:/home# sudo kill -9 3044
root@2c2379a99b47:/homek# sudo service redis-server restart
Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
Starting redis-server: redis-server.
root@2c2379a99b47:/home# sudo service redis-server status 
redis-server is running
```

Answer (score 12):

This works for me:

```sh
$ killall redis-server
```

And combining everything in one line:

```
$ killall redis-server; redis-server
```

Answer (score 9):

So as it says, the process is already running so the best to do is to stop it, analyse and restart it and todo so here are the following commands :

```
redis-cli ping #should return 'PONG'
```

And this solved my issue:

```
$ ps -ef |grep redis

root      6622  4836  0 11:07 pts/0    00:00:00 grep redis
redis     6632     1  0 Jun23 ?        04:21:50 /usr/bin/redis-server *:6379
```

Locate redis process, and stop it!

```
$ kill -9 6632
$ service redis restart


Stopping redis-server: [  OK  ]
Starting redis-server: [  OK  ]


$ service redis status
```

Otherwise if all this doesn't work just try to type `redis-cli`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 8):

I read the documentation on http://www.redis.io , I opened the `redis.conf` file to configure the `redis-server`, its located at `/etc/redis/redis.conf`

```
$ sudo subl /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Instead of sublime editor you can use editor of your choice, viz. nano, vi, emacs, vim, gedit.

In this file I uncommented the `#bind 127.0.0.1` line. Hence, instead of `0.0.0.0:6379` now its `127.0.0.1:6379`

Restart the redis server

```
$ sudo service redis-server restart
```

It will state, The server is now ready to accept connections on port `6379`

This will put your server up, For any more detailed configuration and settings you can follow this [redis-server on ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-redis-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to use the command param `-ef`,

```
ps -ef|grep redis
```

the `-ef`means

```
-A      Display information about other users' processes, including those
         without controlling terminals.
-e      Identical to -A.

-f      Display the uid, pid, parent pid, recent CPU usage, process start
        time, controlling tty, elapsed CPU usage, and the associated com-
        mand.  If the -u option is also used, display the user name
        rather then the numeric uid.  When -o or -O is used to add to the
        display following -f, the command field is not truncated as se-
        verely as it is in other formats.
```

then kill the pid

```
kill -9 $pid
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try

`$ make`

then

`$ sudo cp src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/` on terminal to install the redis and it's redis-cli command.

finally, you can use the `redis-cli shutdown` command. Hope this answer could help you.

Answer (score 3):

I am very late to answer this, but this is the solution worked for me, I think since I was using redis in docker, I could not fully kill the redis server.
This is what helped me, firstly I stoped the redis server via the command

```
sudo systemctl stop redis
```

then run the redis server via the command

```
redis-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Killing the process that was running after booting in the OS worked for me. To prevent redis from starting at startup in Ubuntu OS:

```
sudo systemctl disable redis-server
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I tried several times to kill the port manually and didn't work. So I took the easy path, reinstallation and worked like charm after that. If you're in Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt remove redis-server // No purge needed
sudo apt update
sudo apt install redis-server // Install once again
sudo systemctl status redis-server  // Check status of the service
redis-server    // initializes redis
```

Not the most technical-wise path, but nothing else worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me:

```
killall redis-server
```

Answer (score 0):

It may also happen if you installed Redis via `snap` and are trying to run it from somewhere else.
If this is the case, you can stop the service via `sudo snap stop redis`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but when I first time installed redis and faced this message, turned out that's due to the redis-server first of all takes configure parameters or path/to/redis.conf, so when I passed nothing after "redis-server" it was trying to execute default redis.conf (bind 127.0.0.1, port 6379 ...) thereby overwrite the existing default redis.conf (which contains same "bind" and "port"!!). That's why I've seen this error, but it's possibly you have another reasons

Answer (score 0):

sudo service redis-server stop

Then

redis-server

This two command solved my issue

Answer (score -1):

The problem shows that the default port that redis uses `6379`is already in use by some other process.
**So simply change the port of redis server**

`redis-server --port 7000` will start a Redis server using port number 7000.
and then
`redis-cli -p 7000` - Now use this to make your client listen at this port.